# Angular 2: Class binding doesn't update when data is changed in separate component

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to add an underline on the `active-item` in my NavBar component by binding the return value of the `isActive()` function. `isActive()` compares the url path with the string value passed in and returns true or false.

When I click on either item in the NavBar component, the `isActive()` function runs and the underline displays as expected on the NavBar element that corresponds to the page I navigated to.

However when I click an anchor tag *outside* of the NavBar component, the `isActive()` function doesn't get run again, so the underline remains on the navbar element for the previous page:

[image: Class binding refresh issue]

NavBar HTML:

```
<div class="anchor-wrapper" [class.active-item]="isActive('/dashboard')"> 
    <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
</div>
<div class="anchor-wrapper" [class.active-item]="isActive('/inventory')">
    <a [routerLink]="['/inventory']">Inventory</a>
</div>
```

NavBar TS:

```
isActive(path) {
    return (url.parse(window.location.href).pathname === path) ? true : false;
}
```

Dashboard HTML:

```
<a (click)="onVehicleStatusClick()" RouterLinkActive="active"> {{promotedCount}} </a>
```

Dashboard TS:

```
onVehicleStatusClick(){
    this.router.navigate(['/inventory']);
}
```

How do I ensure that `isActive()` runs again when I navigate to another route outside of the NavBar component?

Many thanks from an Angular newbie

Comment: what about using built in routerLinkActive ? Have you tried it?

Comment: I saw routerLinkActive in the legacy code, but after checking the Angular documentation just now, I don't think it was being used properly. Lemme try and I'll let you know!

Comment: It is stable: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: It worked! If you want to post it as an answer, i'll accept it. thanks a ton

Comment: Sure. no problem.  I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use routerLinkActive directive as follows:

NavBar HTML:

```
<div class="anchor-wrapper" routerLinkActive="isActive('/dashboard')"> 
    <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
</div>
<div class="anchor-wrapper" routerLinkActive="isActive('/inventory')">
    <a [routerLink]="['/inventory']">Inventory</a>
</div
```

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)